# The requested address is not valid in its context

Tags: c#, sockets

Below code is giving the error that request address is not valid,

I am trying with all below options,

1. IPAddress.Any
2. 127.0.0.0
3. Machine IP

   ```
   IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 514);

       UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
       client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
       client.Client.Bind(localEndPoint);
       client.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Any);
       client.MulticastLoopback = true;
       client.BeginReceive(MessageReceived, null);
       Console.ReadLine();
   ```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The requested address i
>   s not valid in its context
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.setMulticastOption(SocketOptionName optionName,
>   MulticastOption MR)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, S
>   ocketOptionName optionName, Object optionValue)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress multicastAddr)
>      at UDPListner.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: ["The multicast address range is 224.0.0.0 to 239.255.255.255"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekd1t784(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: It means you cannot pass `IPAddress.Any`, nor `127.0.0.1`, nor the machine's IP to `JoinMulticastGroup()`.